# Excel VBA to Word Document - Font Size fit to page / line?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have code that works perfectly fine, the problem comes with managing font size.  Currently it opens templates and changes a price, but I am looking to change the font size to fit the page.  For example $1,129 would be size 210 in our font, but $2,229 would be 180 to fit the same space ($1,119 would be 230). Luckily anything with only 3 digits is always 230 due to height constraints.

```
For Each oRange In WordDoc.StoryRanges
                        With oRange
                            With .Find
                                .Forward = False
                                .Text = "$"
                            End With
                            If .Find.Execute Then
                                .Expand Unit:=4
                                .Text = "$" & PriceString
                            End If
                        End With
                    Next oRange
```

A pretty basic find and replace.

Is there a default setting for fit to page / line when printing text to word or will I need to construct a Character counting system?

<s>The only number that seems to be causing a problem is 1, so I could simply count the number of 1's and adjust based on that if necessary.  From what I can tell all other numbers are the same size.</s>  I went ahead and wrote the 1 counter, but it turns out 4,6,9 are bigger than everything else.  I suppose I can count those as well.

This change is always the last line of the page if that is helpful.

Comment: “Is there a default setting for fit to page / line” - no.

Comment: Thanks Timothy.  I went ahead and just wrote some tedious nested IFs for every circumstance.